# Resultado de Query se duplica

Tags: mysql

Estoy trabajando en MySQL

La script de mi base de datos

```
-- Tabla solicitudes
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `solicitudes` (
`id_solicitud` int(11) NOT NULL,
`fecha_recoleccion` date DEFAULT NULL,
`gas_r22` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
`status` varchar(50)
);

INSERT INTO `solicitudes`
 (`id_solicitud`,`fecha_recoleccion`,`gas_r22`,`status`)
VALUES
(1,'2019-05-12',50, 'Atendida'),
(2,'2019-05-22',20, 'Atendida'),
(3,'2019-05-23',20, 'En proceso');

-- Enfriadores

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `enfriadores` (
  `id_enfriador` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `id_solicitud` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `enfriador_una_pta` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `enfriador_dos_pta` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
);

INSERT INTO `enfriadores` 
 ( `id_enfriador`, `id_solicitud`, `enfriador_una_pta`, `enfriador_dos_pta` )
  VALUES
   (1, 1,'45', '23'),
   (2, 2,'30', '20'),
   (3, 3,'3', '21');
```

En la siguiente `query` **se están duplicando mis resultados y no está tomando en cuenta la condicional** `WHERE status = 'Atendida'`ya que se están sumando todas las cantidades de todos los status

```
SELECT 
 (select SUM(enf.enfriador_una_pta) from enfriadores enf) as tot_una_pta,
 (select SUM(enf.enfriador_dos_pta) from enfriadores enf) as tot_dos_pta,
 (select DISTINCT SUM(sol.gas_r22) from solicitudes sol) as tot_gas_r22
FROM `solicitudes`
WHERE `status` = 'Atendida'
```

Actualmente se duplica así 
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Disculpa, quisiera preguntar... que es lo que buscas con esa consulta???... La lógica de poner un from y un where después de seleccionar información de esa forma, en este caso esta demás... la información que seleccionas es independiente al realizarlo en forma de otra consulta...  Y para comprobarlo, puedes ejecutar esas 3 consultas de forma independiente(te darán los mismos valores de todas formas)

Comment: [Te podrían votar negativamente porque sin datos de ejemplo no se logra comprender bien tu pregunta](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/3794/21)

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT SUM(e.enfriador_una_pta) AS totalUno, SUM(e.enfriador_dos_pta) AS totalDos,
SUM(s.gas_r22) AS totalGas
FROM enfriadores AS e 
INNER JOIN solicitudes AS s ON s.id_solicitud = e.id_solicitud
WHERE s.status = 'Atendida'
```

Eso creo que cumple con lo que buscas, espero que te sirva o te guie por lo menos.

Comment: gracias por tu respuesta @Ziggy Pop, la sumatoria de enfriadores va bien pero los resultados de gas_r22 se están duplicando, está ocurriendo algo ahí, por ejemplo cuando mi resultado debería de ser 10 me da 15 y  en 6 me da 9

Answer (score 0):

**Edición**

- Obtén el resultado que esperas mediante un `JOIN` implícito, invocando las 2 tablas en la misma consulta.
- Iguala la llave foránea de la tabla `enfriadores` con la llave primaria de la tabla `solicitudes`
- En el `FROM` separadas por coma invoca ambas tablas
- Al final con un operador `AND` indicas que también se debe cumplir para mostrar los resultados que la columna `status` sea `Atendida`

**Consulta**

```
SELECT solicitudes.status, SUM(enfriadores.enfriador_una_pta) AS Uno,
       SUM(solicitudes.gas_r22) AS Tres,
       SUM(enfriadores.enfriador_dos_pta) AS Dos
FROM enfriadores, solicitudes 
WHERE enfriadores.id_solicitud = (SELECT solicitudes.id_solicitud)
AND (solicitudes.status = "Atendida");
```

*Sin embargo me parece mas adecuada y funcional la respuesta del otro usuario*

Comment: Hola, creo que en tu consulta no funciona correctamente en el where, suma todo por mas que el status no sea = 'Atendida'

Comment: @ZiggyPop toda la razón, gracias por la observación; me confundió en un inicio la consulta de la OP, dejo una opción pero como indico la tuya me parece la respuesta que debe ser aceptada